# Create Identity without CN at the certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, x509certificate2

I have a p12 certificate for a WebService (I've tested the certificate with SoapUI and it works, and I can access the URL with a WebBrowser).

The problem is that I can't consume the WebService with my c# development. When I try to access the webservice, returns the error message "Cannot create DNS identity probably due to the lack of CN parameter".

How can I override this? I've tried the CreateX509CertificateIdentity, but the error remains.

Comment: You have to include the "CN=myCnName"

Comment: either, Subject field or Subject Alternative Names (SAN) extension must present.

Comment: I know it @MikeCheel, but the problem is that I'm not the one who generates the certificate. But SoapUI works fine with the certificate, while Visual Studio 2012 not

Answer (score 0):

When you access your webservice on i.e. http://localhost/webservice url then your CN=localhost. If you want to make the webservice available at multiple urls then you need to specify all DNS addresses in subject alternative name (SAN) in the extensions of your certificate. Of course the certificate has to be trusted by client and server.